# Apply function on a two dataframe rows

Tags: pandas

Given a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})

col1    col2
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

I would like to do something equivalent to this using a function but without passing "by value" or as a global variable the whole dataframe (it could be huge and then it would give me a memory error):

```
i = -1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if i < 0:
        i = index
        continue
    c1 = df.loc[i][0] + df.loc[index][0]
    c2 = df.loc[i][1] + df.loc[index][1]
    df.ix[index, 0] = c1
    df.ix[index, 1] = c2
    i = index

col1    col2
0   1   4
1   3   9
2   6   15
```

i.e., I would like to have a function which will give me the previous output:

```
def my_function(two_rows):
   row1 = two_rows[0]
   row2 = two_rows[1]
   c1 = row1[0] + row2[0]
   c2 = row1[1] + row2[1]
   row2[0] = c1
   row2[1] = c2
   return row2

df.apply(my_function, axis=1)
df

col1    col2
0   1   4
1   3   9
2   6   15
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Arguments are not passed by value in Python. In fact, there aren't variables in Python, and hence no pass by value or by reference, but it's more similar to pass by reference than by value.

Answer (score 1):

What you've demonstrated is a `cumsum`

```
df.cumsum()

   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     3     9
2     6    15
def f(df):
    n = len(df)
    r = range(1, n)
    for j in df.columns:
        for i in r:
            df[j].values[i] += df[j].values[i - 1]

    return df

f(df)
```

To define a function as a loop that does this in place

## Slow cell by cell

```
def f(df):
    n = len(df)
    r = range(1, n)
    for j in df.columns:
        for i in r:
            df[j].values[i] += df[j].values[i - 1]

    return df

f(df)

   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     3     9
2     6    15
```

---

### Compromise between memory and efficiency

```
def f(df):
    for j in df.columns:
        df[j].values[:] = df[j].values.cumsum()

    return df

f(df)

f(df)

   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     3     9
2     6    15
```

---

Note that you don't need to return `df`.  I chose to for convenience.

Comment: Thanks for your quit answer but it isn't what I was looking for. Sorry, if I didn't explain properly. 

What I showed in the function was just an example, I don't really want to sum the two previous rows, so I won't need to use the '_cumsum_' function (though it is good to know it ;)). 

On the other hand, the _f_ function you're showing is making a copy of my dataframe instead of updating it on the fly. If I do this, it will cause a memory error.

Comment: Just like you showed an example, my post is also an example of how to edit in place.